# how to import json data file and use it in a react component?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm new to react and confused about how to import, export, and render components.  I have a fakeData.json file located in the same src/components folder as the component I'm trying to render.  Here is the index.html

```
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

Here is the index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is the app.js

```
import './App.css';
import './components/WatchlistTable.js';
import 'rsuite/lib/styles/index.less';

  function App() {
    return <WatchlistTable />
  }
export default App;
```

Here is where I get confused in src/components/WatchlistTable.js.  It is a rsuite table.  I try to import the fakeData.json file, which is located in the same components folder, like this:
import fakeData from 'fakeData.json';
But it gives error like "Module not found: Can't resolve fakeData.json". So I try another way.

```
import {fakeData} from 'fakeData.json';
```

But it gives same error.  In the Visual Studio Code editor I notice message like: "there is no fakeData.json in the public folder."

So I make a copy and put it there.  Now VSC error disappears but other error remains.
The fakeData.json file looks like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "avartar": "url/128.jpg",
      blah blah blah...
    },
]
```

So I try another way.  I change fakeData.json in components folder to fakeData.js and add

```
const fakeData = [
```

But same error.  So I try:

```
const fakeData = require('fakeData.js');
```

But same error.  Suggestions?

**EDIT**:  Per Ridik, I now have this in WatchlistTable.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import fakeData from 'fakeData';
```

And I have

```
export default fakeData;
```

at the end of the fakeData.js file.  But still getting same error:
./src/components/WatchlistTable.js

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'fakeData' in
> 'C:\Users\Greg\Projects\react-demos\backtester-rsuite\src\components'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly import your json array from the JSON file in react. To achieve that you must store your JSON  array in a variable and then `export default` your JSON array. By Doing this you can easily `import` it in your component.

`FakeData.js`

```
const fakeData = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "avartar": "url/128.jpg",
      blah blah blah...
    },
]


export default fakeData // you must export it to use in another file.
```

Then in any component use it like

```
import fakeData from './Destination_of_file/fakeData.js' 

or

Way 2 // recomended
import fakeData from './Destination_of_file/fakeData'
```

Comment: Still getting the same error: ./src/components/WatchlistTable.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fakeData' in 'C:\Users\Greg\Projects\react-demos\backtester-rsuite\src\components'

Comment: I posted your suggestions in the EDIT section

Comment: Your route is wrong ... the destination should be "./fakedata". Please include './' before writing file name if the file is in the same folder.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.  Now it works.  Not sure why, it's in the same folder as Watchlist.js.  Strange.  Thank you Ritik!

Comment: Because You don't write the full path in React or any Js  code. The root folder for them is the one with NodeModules.  For more Go here https://medium.com/@baintonw/importing-and-exporting-in-react-91bf7c3e5e45

Answer (score 1):

In your import statement you have to provide the relative path of the file. Otherwise it looks into public directory in your project. And also instead of using named import syntax use default import syntax. i.e., in your case use below statement to import that json file in your component.
`import jsonFile from "./fakeData.json";`